# Why is my code allocating an unnecessary amount of bytes from my w10_text.dat file? (OOP345 SENECA)

Tags: c++11

```
void SecureData::backup(const char* file) {
    if (!text)
        throw std::string("\n***No data stored***\n");
    else if (!encoded)
        throw std::string("\n***Data is not encoded***\n");
    else {
        // open binary file
        std::ofstream is;
        is.open(file, std::ios::out);
        // write binary file here
        if (is.fail())
        {
            throw std::string("\n***No file could be opened " + std::string(file) + " ***\n");
        }
        else
        {
    for (int i = 0; i < nbytes; i++)
            {
                is << text[i];
            }
        }
        
    }
}
void SecureData::restore(const char* file, char key) {
    // open binary file
    std::ifstream os;
    os.open(file, std::ios::in);
    if (os.fail())
    {
        throw std::string("\n***No file could be opened " + std::string(file) + " ***\n");
    }
    else
    {
        nbytes = 0;
        char tempchar = 0;
        while (os.good())
        {
            os >> tempchar;
            nbytes++; //!< count number of chars

        }
        std::cerr << nbytes << std::endl;
        text = new char[nbytes]; //!< allocate memory here
        os.clear();
        os.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
        for (int i = 0; i < nbytes; i++)
        {
            os >> text[i]; //!< read binary file here
        }
    }
    

    std::cout << "\n" << nbytes + 1 << " bytes copied from binary file "
        << file << " into memory (null byte included)\n";
    encoded = true;

    // decode using key
    code(key);[enter image description here][1]
    std::cout << "Data decrypted in memory\n\n";
}
```

I believe the error lies in my backup(const char * file) however I do not know where the issue is. I would really appreciate feed back and a second pair of eyes. Cheers!
As this is for a class I also included the lab link that I am completing, as well as a image of my output bellow:
[https://scs.senecac.on.ca/~oop345/pages/workshops/w10.html](https://scs.senecac.on.ca/%7Eoop345/pages/workshops/w10.html)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMVsL.jpg

Answer (score 0):

```
os.read(text, nbytes);
```

Replaced the for look with the code above worked. I assume the ">>" operators was the issue.

`for (int i = 0; i < nbytes; i++)
{ 
os >> text[i]; //! read binary file here
};`